# Persistence deployment issue

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence.xml

I have a hibernate project, which uses JPA.

my persistence.xml contents is as follows:

```
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="Demo-PU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
  <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>java:/DemoDS</non-jta-data-source> 
    <class>com.demo.framework.entity.ReportDefinitionEntity</class> 
    <properties>

<!--  Database connection -->
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://192.168.9.110:3306/demoDB" />
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root" />
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="root" />

 <!--  Hibernate dialect  -->
  <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
<!--  Output goodies
  -->
  <property name="hibernate.query.jpaql_strict_compliance" value="true" />
  <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
  <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="false" />
   <!--  Cache
  -->
  <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data" value="true" />
  <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider" />

    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Now when I run it using eclipse I don't have a problem, but when I deploy it in Jboss, I get the below error:

> ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error
>   installing to Start:
>   name=persistence.unit:unitName=#Demo-PU
>   state=Create
>   java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence
>   cannot be cast to
>   javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider

And here is the list of Jar that I have

```
activation.jar
antlr-2.7.6.jar
asm-attrs.jar
asm.jar
cglib-2.1.3.jar
commons-collections-2.1.1.jar
commons-logging-1.1.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
ehcache-1.2.3.jar
hibernate-annotations.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations.jar
hibernate-entitymanager.jar
hibernate-tools.jar
hibernate3.jar
javassist.jar
javax.persistence.jar
jdbc2_0-stdext.jar
jta.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.0.5-bin.jar
xml-writer.jar
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Also I have tried to use ejb3-persistence.jar instead of javax.persistence.jar

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `ClassCastException` is caused by having two copies of the `javax.persistence` APIs in your system (one in the common classloader provided by JBoss and the one in your app). When running on JBoss, you are just not supposed to provide this API in your application, don't package it.

By the way, it seems you're using a JPA 2.0 `persistence.xml` but I'm not convinced you're using the JPA 2.0 implemenation of Hibernate (actually, you seem to be using a pretty old version since I can see `commons-logging.jar`). You should probably fix that i.e. use the 1.0 version of `persistence.xml`.

Actually, you should very likely use a different `persistence.xml` when running on JBoss (using a JTA entity manager and a `jta-data-source`). And it seems weird to mix data source usage and Hibernate built-in connection pool.